# How to set up different uploaded file storage locations for Laravel 5.2 in local deployment and AWS EB w/ S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel 5.2 application where users can send a file by POST, the application stores that file in a certain location and retrieves it on demand later. I'm using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. For local development on my machine, I would like the files to store in a specified local folder on my machine. And when I deploy to AWS-EB, I would like it to automatically switch over and store the files in S3 instead. So I don't want to hard code something like `\Storage::disk('s3')->put(...)` because that won't work locally.

What I'm trying to do here is similar to what I was able to do for environment variables for database connectivity... I was able to find some great tutorials where you create an `.env.elasticbeanstalk` file, create a config file at `~/.ebextiontions/01envconfig.config` to automatically replace the standard `.env` file on deployment, and modify a few lines of your `database.php` to automatically pull the appropriate variable.

How do I do something similar with file storage and retrieval?

Comment: I'm starting to think there's an easy way to accomplish this, but I haven't yet determined it. Does AWS-EB automatically point to S3 for "local" storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Got it working. In `/config/filesystems.php`, I changed:

```
'default' => 'local',
```

to:

```
'default' => env('DEFAULT_STORAGE') ?: 'local',
```

In my `.env.elasticbeanstalk` file (see the original question for an explanation of what this is), I added the following (I'm leaving out my actual key and secret values):

```
DEFAULT_STORAGE=s3
S3_KEY=[insert your key here]
S3_SECRET=[insert your secret here]
S3_REGION=us-west-2
S3_BUCKET=cameraflock-clips-dev
```

Note that I had to specify my region as `us-west-2` even though S3 shows my environment as `Oregon`.

In my upload controller, I don't specify a disk. Instead, I use:

```
\Storage::put($filePath, $filePointer, 'public');
```

This way, it always uses my "default" disk for the `\Storage` operation. If I'm in my local environment, that's my `public` folder. If I'm in AWS-EB, then my Elastic Beanstalk `.env` file goes into effect and `\Storage` defaults to S3 with appropriate credentials.